# Use X2JS library in Cloud Code (Parse.com)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to use the `x2js.js` library on my cloud code.

You can find the .js code here: http://pastebin.com/6P15DFwB ant the project's site here: https://code.google.com/p/x2js/

I put this line in my main.js file: `var JSONConverter = require('cloud/xml2json.js');` 
but I can't use the library in my code.

I tried in so many ways, but i can't access to the library's methods.

```
var json = JSONConverter.xml_str2json(thefile.buffer.toString());
```

Can someone help me? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks